# How to project EF Linq result to IEnumerable<IBook> where Book Explicitly implements in IBook?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

Trying to Project a EF linq result into IEnumerable of interfaces, something simialr to below but can't get it working, any hints is apreciated:

```
                IEnumerable<IBook> books = (from b in context.Library
                                                  (select new (Book() as IBook)
                                                  {
                                                      Id = b.Id,
                                                      Title = b.Title
                                                  }).AsEnumerable<IBook>;
```

Error : Cannot convert Lambda expression to type string because it is not delegate type.

PS : It is explicit interface implementation so I can't just use the following that works with implicit interface implementation:

```
                IEnumerable<IBooks> books = (from b in context.Library
                                                  select new Book()
                                                  {
                                                      Id = b.Id,
                                                      Title = b.Title
                                                  }).AsEnumerable<IBook>();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
IEnumerable<IBooks> books = (from b in context.Library
    select new Book
    {
        Id = b.Id,
        Title = b.Title
    }).Cast<IBook>();
```

Or you can do this:

```
IEnumerable<IBooks> books = (from b in context.Library
    select new Book
    {
        Id = b.Id,
        Title = b.Title
    } as IBook);
```

Third option (for your explicit interface):

```
IEnumerable<IBook> books = context.Library.Select(b =>
{
    IBook book = new Book();  //as IBook - Might need a cast here 
    book.Id = b.Id;
    book.Title = b.Title;
    return book;
};
```

Comment: Thank you, but the properties Id and Title are explicitly implemented, compiler complained about the Book not having Id, or Title defined. I have implemented the interface implicitly and Explicitly

Comment: See my edit above.  I'm not sure how practical explicit interfaces are.  I tend to stay away from them b/c it prevents you from using the nice object initializers such as `new Book { Id = b.Id }`.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is sort of a 'no brainer' but make sure this namespace is imported because I have seen that error caused by missing over and over again.

```
using System.Linq;
```

If I remember correctly it will compile but will throw that error at runtime if that namespace isn't declared.

Also if you want to clean up the LINQ query (I love using lambda's) I believe this lamda expression will work for your situation.

```
IEnumerable<IBooks> books = (context.Library.Select(b => new Book{ b.Id, b.Title })).Cast<IBook>();
```

Comment: Adam you are correct, excpet this time it was already there. But I had to check it after you comment thx